# Install Fedora desktop on Centos?

Tags: linux, centos, fedora, desktop, desktop-customization

Hi and thanx in advance :)

So, on my work PC I have pre-installed CentOS 6, which sports a sh*t desktop environment. I would like to know if and how I'll be able to install the Fedora Desktop to it, because as far as I know Fedora and centos are the same, with the exception of the nicer desktop. I've searched the whole web, and nothing I found worked for me. I've noticed I'm able to choose between desktop environments on the user login screen, since at the moment I have 2, which both suck.

All help and tips appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Fedora uses Gnome3 as default. To install

```
yum group install "GNOME Desktop"
```

EDIT: As it looks like CentOS6 does not offer official Gnome3 Packages. Sorry.

Comment: Ive tried that. This is what I get: 
Warning: Group GNOME Desktop does not exist.
No packages in any requested group available to install or update.
This leads me to believe I'm missing a repo, however I cant seem to find which...

Comment: You are right, I'm sorry. It looks like CentOS6 has no repos for Gnome3.

Comment: So a big "No, not happening" then?

Comment: If you are not ok with updateing your system to the latest CentOS (7 - which comes with Gnome3 perdefault) it is probably a No. You could build the source yourself but I think this would be an much bigger pain than to update to CentOS.